Hexo deploy successfully but Github page is 404
Hexo deploy successfully and the blog works on localhost but 404 on github page
I am using hexo to build my own blog.After run hexo d,my github repo did not trigger any deploy and I visited yasuoskywalker.github.io and met 404 page.
However,My blog can be visited in localhost by running hexo s.
How Can I fix this problem?
my comfig.yml:
deploy:
  - type: git
    repo: git@github.com:YasuoSkywalker/YasuoSkywalker.github.io.git
    branch: master

my github repo:YasuoSkywalker.github.io

Sounds like a good ticket for Github support to address for you
